# Android navigation drawer toolbar is missing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I have an launcher activity with navigaton drawer. When I add map into that launcher activity I dont see any toolbar so I can't control navigation drawer. Here how my activity looks now:
[image]

And here how it should look like (I need to have this toolbar)
[image]

And the navigation drawer should overlap map like this[image]

So here's my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_nav);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mapView = new MapView(this);

    MapHandler.getMapHandler().init(this, mapView);

    addMarkers();
}
```

as you can see I add toolbar to activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

here's part of MapHandler init method()

```
mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(tileRendererLayer);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    activity.addContentView(mapView, params);
```

here's code from manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".map.MapNavActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT my nav activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_map_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_map_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_map_nav_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_map_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="aplikacija.zveju.rinkodara.com.zvejuaplikacija.map.MapNavActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_map_nav" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please, add your activity xml layout.

Comment: @Majestic I add xml file

Comment: It's only guess, but maybe you use CoordinatorLayout with maps? If so, AppBar will show up only with behavior attached to it

Comment: @David I don't see where you attach mapView to you layout. I think, that it overlaps your tollbar. Try to add MapView in content_map_nav.xml and in onCreate() try to findViewById().

Comment: may be its because of style  check your style in resources

Comment: try to add "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to your <MapView> in xml

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with Majestic help. Thank You! I add this code in `content_map_nav.xml`

```
<org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView>
```

and in mainactivity instead of this `mapView = new MapView()` I write this `mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);` and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

May be you have replace ConstraintLayout in content_main.xml with a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, if you want to use a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout you should keep  but wrap your layout like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.gmail.farhadkargaran.myapplication.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```